# In Opendaylight, we send openflow's multipart request and why wireshark can see accumulate multipart request in a single packet?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, opendaylight, openflow

Like this figure,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsyTP.png)
I can find many openflow1.3 which are multipart requests in this packet, but I don't know why happened here?
Actually, isn't it only one openflow1.3 here ?
It is related to openflowjava do serialize, wireshark, NIC, tcp nagle's algorithim?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a byte stream, i.e. packet has no semantic from the perspective of the application layer (i.e. OpenFlow). At the transport level there can be multiple application layer "messages" in a single TCP packet, messages cross packet boundaries etc - it does not matter for the application. While often TCP packet boundaries are also message boundaries because of timing in the application and maybe a disabling of NAGLE algorithm, the assumption that TCP packet boundaries are always message boundaries is wrong and any reliance on this will often cause sporadic and hard to reproduce problems.

And based on this what you see is also not a "multipart request". These are just multiple OpenFlow messages (application level) send at the same time or shortly after each other and they are put together into the same transport level entity (packet) since this way it is less overhead to transport each message.

Comment: Thanks for your correction and reading my poor english!